# When a user presses Enter in a text input field, what causes a submit button to get a click event?

Tags: html, cross-browser

I think if we set a `click` event handler on the submit button, it is not as preferred as setting a `submit` event on the form.

But I found that we can do

http://jsfiddle.net/MtLca/6/

```
document.getElementById('the-button').onclick = function (evt) {
    alert("That's good I am clicked...");
}
```

with the HTML:

```
<form method="get">
    <input type="text" name="someVar">
    <input id="the-button" type="submit">
</form>
```

and when a user press Enter on the text input field, the submit button will get a `click` event.  It works on Chrome, Firefox, and Safari, and when tried on IE 6, it won't trigger the event.  So it seems like it is a browser implementation that whenever a form is submitted, the (first) submit button will get a `click` event before the form gets a `submit` event (see http://jsfiddle.net/MtLca/12/ ).  Does someone know the history and evolution of browsers know about the details for what happened above?

Comment: I'm not sure, but consider the possibility that there is no submit button. If you're looking for a form submission, the event you should be checking is the form's `submit` event, and not `onclick` of the submit button. Just pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is still the case but at one point in IE6 having a form of one text field caused the enter to not submit the form.  Try adding an additional input and see if it works then.